# breeze BeforeSaveEntity does not save calculated value

Tags: breeze

i need to calculate some values on the serverside when a specific entity gets updated.
if i update the entity the following code gets executed (C_CompletePrice gets set) and it even gets reflected on clientside (clientside breeze gets all the properties nicely back)
but when i check the db nothing is saved. so when clearing the browser cache and checking the entity again there are the old values...

```
    private bool BeforeSaveTransaction(tblTransactions transaction, EntityInfo info)
    {
        transaction.C_CompletePrice = 11111111;
        return true;
        ...

  protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        var entity = entityInfo.Entity;
        if (entity is tblTransactions)
        {
            return BeforeSaveTransaction(entity as tblTransactions, entityInfo);
        }
        ...
```

i'm using breeze 1.4.6

on the server i'm using Breeze.WebApi and Breeze.WebApi.EF

the model i'm using: http://pastebin.com/Dc03DrNe

**Update**

```
    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
        foreach (Type entityType in saveMap.Keys)
        {
            if (entityType.Name == "tblTransactions")
            {
                foreach (EntityInfo ei in saveMap[entityType])
                {
                    CalculateTransaction(ei);
                }
            }
        }
        return base.BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap);
    }

    private  void CalculateTransaction(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        tblTransactions transaction = (tblTransactions) entityInfo.Entity;

        transaction.C_CompletePrice = 1234567;
        ...
```

Using `BeforeSaveEntities` results in the same strange behaviour:

- Entites on the client gets updatet :)
- DB not :(

So before i'll use now @dominictus solution (overriding SaveAll) i'm kindly asking for the **purpose** of those methods i've used (**bool BeforeSaveEntity(...) and BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap)**). I've consulted the doc and i've watched bryan noyes brilliant pluralsight course but still my simple mind doesn't get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update the `EntityInfo.OriginalValuesMap` as described in the [`ContextProvider` topic](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider#OriginalValuesMap)?

Comment: hi ward, hmmm looks like i should just rtgm (g for great) a bit better :) it worked!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. I wrote that bit AFTER reading your question and realizing we needed to talk about this technique. You've made the docs better. Thx

Comment: If this was the answer you needed, would you please mark it as the correct answer so that others may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I do it a bit different. Here is an example where I save a timestamp when object was changed. This is a method in my Context class.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (
            var entry in
                this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where((e => (e.State == (EntityState) Breeze.WebApi.EntityState.Added || e.State == (EntityState) Breeze.WebApi.EntityState.Modified))))
        {
            if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(MyClass))
            {
                var entity = entry.Entity as MyClass;
                if (entity != null) entity.UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
     }
```

In your case, you could just write: `entity.C_CompletePrice = 11111111;`

As for method `BeforeSaveEntity` I prefer using `BeforeSaveEntities`. Check breeze documentation for examples.

Comment: thanks again :) i've tried with BeforeSaveEntities (see my Update) but without success.
Overriding SaveChanges for this purpose i would consider as a workaround for a very common task ;) (if it works)

Comment: I edited my response (added return statement) so you could see that I'm not really overriding SaveChanges, just adding something that happens before entities really are saved. Doesn't seem like a workaround in my opinion. Could you check if your saveMap really changed? (place a breakpoint)

Comment: thanks, didn't think of using linq as well to query for the state. so i'm giving my spare points which i can give to your solution even i'm going with wards answer.

Comment: Hi @Dominictus, your Idea is very good. but would you like to tell me that, how can i override SaveChanges() method. i did not find any override method of SaveChanges(). please give me full example. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Shohel, you can override SaveChanges in your context class `public Class MyContextClass : DbContext`